# Linux bridge of my own making: arp request never succeeds

Tags: linux, networking, wireless, arp, raw-sockets

I wrote a bridge (layer 2 switch) using my Boost.Asio extension. We can easily make additional sockets, endpoints and protocols which meet their type requirements. And my extension uses linux packet socket with `AF_PACKET`, `SOCK_RAW` and `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` (See [`man 7 packet`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet) for more information about packet socket).

Here's an example for explaining how my bridge works:

```
[PC1] <----> IF1[PC2]IF2 <----> [PC3]
```

Bridge connects the network interfaces(e.g. eth0) IF1 and IF2 so PC1 can communicate with PC3 via bridge running on PC2. The way to connect interfaces is sending packets received from IF1 to IF2 (and vice versa)

My bridge works under the wired connections as expected, but it doesn't work under the wireless connections. So I tried to find what causes this problem and I found that ARP request never succeeded.

The actual environment which causes this problem is:

```
[PC1] <--wired--> eth0[PC2]wlan0 <--wireless(802.11g)--> [router1]
```

Under the environment above, for example, now PC1 tries to send ping(ICMP) packet to router1. To send it to PC3, PC1 has to know the MAC address of router1 so PC1 sends ARP request to `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` And my bridge running on PC2 receives it from eth0 and send it to wlan0, but router1 never sends arp reply to PC1.

note: SOCK_RAW packets are passed to and from the device driver without any changes in the packet data. (quoted from man page of packet)

What should I do to allow PC1 to communicate with router1?
Thank you.

Edit:
Here is my Boost.Asio extension.
[github: pfpacket/libarex](https://github.com/pfpacket/libarex)

And this is my bridge using above.
[libarex/example/layer2_switch/interface_bridge.cpp](https://github.com/pfpacket/libarex/blob/master/example/layer2_switch/interface_bridge.cpp)

Comment: Are you sure that your stuff works properly with the wireless interface? Can you run a packet sniffer on the router? Because many wireless chipsets (or their drivers at least) do not support sending raw packets with forged MAC adresses, which would be what you have to do to do layer 2 switches (common reason for the Operation not permitted/supported error when trying to bridge together wireless and wired interfaces).

Comment: Have you tried to do the same using ``brctl`` and/or only wired interfaces?

Comment: I ran brctl as root and brctl said "can't add wlan0 to bridge vbr0: Operation not supported". My wireless driver may not supports doing such a thing. But the wireshark listening wlan0 displayed the arp request which my bridge sent to router1. Thank you for your commets.

Comment: Yeah, does the ARP request arrive at the router? It's possible that wireshark sees packages which won't be actually transmitted over the physical layer I guess. If ``brctl`` says it cannot be done, you really should check at the router side. Again, try your code with wired interfaces only to verify that it works outside the scope of wireless driver issues. (Note: I'm one of those who is heavily annoyed by the missing possibility to easily bridge wifi and wired on my notebook, so I feel with you if it doesn't work)

Comment: I don't know the way to check whether or not arp request arrives at the router1 ...

Comment: Can you try to do Ad-Hoc wifi to another machine (instead of and without the router) and ping that over the bridge from PC1?

Comment: I setup Ad-hoc mode by seeing [How to set up an Ad-Hoc wireless?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wireless-674502/) and my another machine can find the Ad-hoc signal but cannot communicate via the Ad-hoc. Are there other ways to check the arrival of arp request. sorry...

Comment: Did you setup static IPs in the Ad-hoc network? Remember that your other machine won't broadcast DHCP, so you have to setup static IPs (preferredly ``192.168.0.xx`` or ``10.xx.yy.zz``) on _all_ involved machines (i.e. _also_ PC1). To verify that it basically works, first try to ping from PC2 (bridge) to the PC3 (other ad hoc machine) — If that doesn't help, is there any way for you to run ``tcpdump`` or similar on the router?

Comment: You could try to run ``tcpdump`` on another client in the wireless network. If its wireless card is in promiscuous mode (``tcpdump`` puts it in that mode), you should see traffic of all other clients that are within range. If you can observe the arp request there, you can be certain that it has been transmitted by your bridge's wireless card. If you don't, however, that's no definitive proof that it hasn't been transmitted, since you might just have missed the packet due to bad air quality or other reasons.

Comment: @LeonWeber does that work in arbitrary encrypted wireless networks?

Comment: @JonasWielicki it should work with pre-shared key encrypted wifi networks; it won't work with personalized encryption keys.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes, I setup static IPs in the Ad-hoc network. (I use 192.168.2.x)

Comment: @LeonWeber Thank you for commenting. I tried that on another machine using my USB-WLAN. But tcpdump on my another machine didn't display arp request from PC1. (of course my bridge listens packets in promiscuous mode) I am stuck.

Comment: @xps_l502 This sounds really as if your wifi adapter is unable to do bridging, even if you write the packets in raw mode. Did you verify the workings of your code by trying to bridge two wired interfaces instead of bridging wifi and wired together?

Comment: @JonasWielicki I hope not. My bridge code works under wired connections surely. I updated my question. See it also please.

Comment: @xps_l502 I cannot imagine anything besides a buggy driver/chipset then. Sorry to say that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing up what we discussed in the comments.

It is a [common problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/114657/linux-ethernet-wireless-bridging) that wireless bridging is problematic (under linux at least, I don't know for others). Investigation has shown that most probably the wireless driver or chipset of the hardware used as bridge is incapable of doing bridging operations (`brctl` failing supports this assumption).

Other possible reasons, as explained in the link above, may be the AP dropping packets with unassociated MAC adresses or the likes.

Additionally, the code works fine for wired interfaces, so it is a hardware problem on some layer. Not much more to say about it.

Comment: At first I guessed the problems were caused by differences of communicating on data link layer between wired and wireless connections. But the problems may be caused by my driver. I will try a little bit more. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As you mentioned, AP mode is for bridging to eth0, the wired interfaces.   But it is not for bridging wlan, and this is part of the physical design - please read:  

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/howto-bridge-wireless-and-wired-network-interfaces-369455/

for an indepth understanding.

Comment: To be highlighted is "WDS" as mentioned in the link above - which is needed if you want to bridge WIFI interface.